# Choosing a pdf file from storage

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open the phone Storage `emulated/storage/0/` and filter only the *pdf* files so that the user can choose.
I tried this code, but in the *fileChoser* I can only open it with tierce application like `DropBox` or `GoogleDrive`. How can I open it using the *android Explorer* ?

```
addPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_PDF_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

EDIT :I tried it both on 4.2 and 6.0,my only choices in *filechooser* are still `Drive` and `Dropbox`

Comment: are you using galaxy s5?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: i still only can open the Drive and Dropbox, can't open Android File explorer

Comment: Does this not allow to choose pdf from file explorer?

Comment: i can't open file explorer

Comment: May be that your file explorer  does not accept this intent. Did you try in another device?